# 2D Character stuttering with a smooth camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character is stuttering when I have a smooth camera following me, although this doesn't annoy me. It annoys the players that play this.

So is there any way to fix this? The smooth camera looks really good imo and so does it to others, but only the stuttering needs to be fixed and it'll look great.

The camera script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cameraTarget; // object to look at or follow
    public GameObject player; // player object for moving

    public float smoothTime = 0.1f;    // time for dampen
    public bool cameraFollowX = true; // camera follows on horizontal
    public bool cameraFollowY = true; // camera follows on vertical
    public bool cameraFollowHeight = true; // camera follow CameraTarget object height
    public float cameraHeight = 2.5f; // height of camera adjustable
    Vector2 velocity; // speed of camera movement

    private Transform thisTransform; // camera Transform

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        thisTransform = transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (cameraFollowX)
        {
            thisTransform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.SmoothDamp(thisTransform.position.x, cameraTarget.transform.position.x, ref velocity.x, smoothTime), thisTransform.position.y, thisTransform.position.z);
        }
        if(cameraFollowY){
            thisTransform.position = new Vector3(thisTransform.position.x, Mathf.SmoothDamp(thisTransform.position.y, cameraTarget.transform.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTime), thisTransform.position.z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what you mean? Maybe post a YouTube video of the issue - basically it sounds like you are saying your character is stuttering but your camera movement is smooth, suggesting the issue isn't with your camera, making the code posted above useless in diagnosing the issue

Comment: [http://youtu.be/gn0FTCOmMkM Here it is.](http://youtu.be/gn0FTCOmMkM) Sorry about that, should have thought about that. .

Comment: Ah, I see, it looks like ping/pong; spring like movement from the dampening in your camera code. You are following you character very tightly, and the smoothing is causing the camera to move in uneven increments. My question is, why are you using this camera code when it looks like you want your camera constrained exactly to your character? If you change the code to `thisTransform.position = cameraTarget.transform.position` you should get exactly the same thing but without the juddering. Are you looking for a slight 'dead zone' in your camera follow?

Comment: If you think about this, logically you are trying to smooth the movement out over 0.1f (I think this is 0.1 seconds but the unity ref isn't clear) but your update is per physics step. This likely means that the character moves say 10 units away from the camera, then the smoothing tries to smooth over 10 units and only does a portion of the move (say 40%, 4 units) then the player moves 10 more units and the camera tries to move another 40% (16 units remaining, 40% = 6.4) so the camera moves a larger increment, then the user moves 10 units again and repeat until juddering occurs!

Comment: Not sure how the deltaTime plugs into the equation though so  I might be wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is due to trying to smooth at a moving target over the physics timestep

I'd just change your code to smooth over a fraction of the camera -> target distance with a tolerance

e.g.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cameraTarget; // object to look at or follow
    public GameObject player; // player object for moving

    public float smoothTime = 0.1f;    // time for dampen
    public bool cameraFollowX = true; // camera follows on horizontal
    public bool cameraFollowY = true; // camera follows on vertical
    public bool cameraFollowHeight = true; // camera follow CameraTarget object height
    public float cameraHeight = 2.5f; // height of camera adjustable
    Vector2 velocity; // speed of camera movement

    private Transform thisTransform; // camera Transform

    // Charleh - added these tweakable values - change as neccessary
    private float threshold = 0.5f; // Threshold distance before camera follows
    private float fraction = 0.7f;  // Fractional distance to move camera by each frame (smooths out the movement)

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        thisTransform = transform;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // Charleh - updated code here
        if (cameraFollowX)
        {
            if(Math.abs(cameraTarget.transform.position.x - thisTransform.position.x) > threshold)
            {
                // target vector = (target.position - this.position)
                // now multiply that by the fractional factor and your camera will
                // move 70% of the distance (0.7f) towards the target. It will never
                // actually reach the target hence the threshold value (but you probably don't
                // want this as it can result in a noticeable SNAP if you try to put the camera
                // on the target when it's beneath the threshold)
                // Edit: oops, missing brackets which are quite important!
                thisTransform.position.x = (cameraTarget.transform.position.x - thisTransform.position.x) * fraction;
            }
        }
        // Repeat for Y
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you, this works fine. Although for some reason when I got out of the dead zone it got about 1000 pixels to the left, and when jumping a thousand pixels down.

Comment: You can also not edit Transform.position.x so I had to create a new Vector3 to it. I'm trying to fix the dead zone bug now.

Comment: Ok - I've never done anything with Unity before so it was mostly just guesswork in terms of the API :P but glad it works for you! If you post your updated code I might be able to spot your bug (if you are lucky haha :))

Comment: I can't see anything obvious, it looks fine to me, so how often does the camera jump these huge amounts? Can you post another video